# How can I set interstitial ads on URL clicks in WebView App?

Tags: url, webview, admob, ads, interstitial

I have implemented following code for interstitial ads .Problem I am facing is that interstitial ad is shown only on first URL click. I want to adjust ads on every URL click or every 5th URL click in WebView app .Help in this regard will highly be appreciated. Following is the code i want to be modified .

```
private WebView webview;
private AdView mAdView;
private InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;
SwipeRefreshLayout mySwipeRefreshLayout;

@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    MobileAds.initialize(this, new OnInitializationCompleteListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInitializationComplete(InitializationStatus initializationStatus) {}
    });
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();

    InterstitialAd.load(this,"ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712", adRequest,
            new InterstitialAdLoadCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onAdLoaded(@NonNull InterstitialAd interstitialAd) {
                    // The mInterstitialAd reference will be null until
                    // an ad is loaded.
                    mInterstitialAd = interstitialAd;
                    Log.i("TAG", "onAdLoaded");
                }

                @Override
                public void onAdFailedToLoad(@NonNull LoadAdError loadAdError) {
                    // Handle the error
                    Log.i("TAG", loadAdError.getMessage());
                    mInterstitialAd = null;
                }
            });


private class WebViewClientDemo extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    //Keep webview in app when clicking links
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        if (mInterstitialAd != null) {
            mInterstitialAd.show(MainActivity.this);
        } else {
            Log.d("TAG", "The interstitial ad wasn't ready yet.");
        }
        return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
    }
```

Comment: after showing interstitial. You need to reload ad . So call InterstitialAd.load again.

Comment: Yes, I have tried many codes for reloading but got errors every time . That is why I asked for help .

Comment: Can you try below code?

Answer (score 0):

You need to load Ad after each show. Create a static counter variable to load it on everyth nth click.

```
 static int instanceCounter = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    LoadInterstitial();
}    

private void LoadInterstitial(){
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    
        InterstitialAd.load(this,"ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712", adRequest,
                new InterstitialAdLoadCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAdLoaded(@NonNull InterstitialAd interstitialAd) {
                        // The mInterstitialAd reference will be null until
                        // an ad is loaded.
                        mInterstitialAd = interstitialAd;
                        Log.i("TAG", "onAdLoaded");
                    }
    
                    @Override
                    public void onAdFailedToLoad(@NonNull LoadAdError loadAdError) {
                        // Handle the error
                        Log.i("TAG", loadAdError.getMessage());
                        mInterstitialAd = null;
                    }
                });
    }

    private class WebViewClientDemo extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        //Keep webview in app when clicking links
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            if (mInterstitialAd != null && isDisplayAdvert()) {
                mInterstitialAd.show(MainActivity.this);
                LoadInterstitial();
            } else {
                Log.d("TAG", "The interstitial ad wasn't ready yet.");
            }
            return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
        }

private bool isDisplayAdvert(){
instanceCounter++;
if(instanceCounter==5){
instanceCounter = 0;
return true;
}
return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks buddy , Now it is showing ad on every single time user clicks in app which can be quite annoying . Can you please write code for managing it's frequency . I mean that  how can I show ad on every 5th or 10th click inside app ? I am new to coding so your help in this regard will highly be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks sir Amod Gokhale . I tried the following code and it is working too .
Would you recommend me about the better one between both codes .

```
private class WebViewClientDemo extends WebViewClient {
    int n = 1;
    @Override
    //Keep webview in app when clicking links
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        if (mInterstitialAd != null) {
            if( n%6 == 0 )
            {
            mInterstitialAd.show(MainActivity.this);
            } n++;
        }
            LoadInterstitial();

        return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);

    }
```